# Different font sizes for different fonts in the same class

Tags: css, fonts

Is it possible to specify different font sizes for different (unembedded) font-families without having to create multiple classes?

For instance, the website requests the user device to load specific fonts for specific languages, and the fonts are specified in the classes, which are assigned per language/script.

Take the example of Arabic, for instance:

```
.lang-ur {font-family: 'Urdu Typesetting', 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu'}

.lang-ar {font-family: 'Arial', 'Times New Roman'}
```

But I want to be able to change the font size of specifically, let's say, 'Urdu Typesetting' without messing with 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu' inside the same class, because it's size is too different from the other.

Comment: Add the font-size declaration to each class, then edit them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem for which solutions are only now starting to appear. Recently introduced in CSS specs are new `font-face` descriptors that allow one to override some of the font's settings. In your case, you're looking for [size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/size-adjust).

If you're already using `@font-face` to import web fonts, it's just a matter of adding the correct properties. If you're using local fonts (`Arial` for example), you'll need to re-declare them with a `@font-face`.

Here's how that would look for Arial:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'custom-arial';
  src: local(Arial);
  size-adjust: 90%;
}

.lang-ar {font-family: 'custom-arial', 'Times New Roman'}
```

---

Sadly Safari doesn't support this descriptor yet. If you need cross-browser compatibility, or if you need to support older browsers, you'll have to use Javascript to determine which font has loaded, and then deduce which font is being used.

For example, with [`document.fonts.check`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check), you can tell whether `.lang-ar` is actually applying `Arial` or `Times New Roman`:

```js
const isArialLoaded = document.fonts.check('1em Arial')
```

However, fonts can also be *currently loading*, and if you call `fonts.check` during that time, you might draw the wrong conclusions (in the example above, you could conclude that Arial is unavailable when it's actually still loading).

If this is your situation, you might want to wait for the [`document.fonts.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/ready) promise:

```
async function whichOne() {
  await document.fonts.ready
  const isArialLoaded = document.fonts.check('1em Arial')
  if (isArialLoaded) {
    // `.lang-ar` will apply the Arial font
  } else {
    // `.lang-ar` will apply the Times New Roman font
  }
}
```

---

Finally, even with this javascript method, you might still have a hard time deducing the *font applied* from just knowing the *font loaded*. This is because for characters that don't exist in the requested family, browsers will use fallback fonts.

- if you write `ہیلو` in Arial, you'll get Arial
- if you write `안녕하세요` in Arial, you'll get a system fallback
- if you write  in Arial, you'll get another system fallback

So basically, the following `<p>` will contain 3 different fonts:

```html
<p class="lang-ar">ہیلو  안녕하세요</p>
```